# Parity tranformation on Lagrangian of free fields

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, parity

> Free lagrangians of scalar, Dirac field and vector fields are always
>   invariant under Parity.

I am able to get this result mathematically, but I want to know if there is any obvious reason for it.

Please comment on why its natural that parity is voilated **only when** interaction between two (or more) fields is introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Because in an isotropic space x is equivalent to -x, this is just Noether theorem.
If you want to see how parity violation is explained in the standard model look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP_violation#CP_violation_in_the_Standard_Model)

Comment: As you say parity is violated "only when" two field interacts, is not entirely true.